# Change display in the comboBox and make it a different text when input it in the cells worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I need help,
how to display in the list combobox with (units)² and when submit it to cells it will be (units)^2 ?

I want the solution code, please

[image]

here is the code that I use:

```
Private Sub Label9_Click()

Set Luas_Aja = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Luas_Aja.Cells(2, 1) = Nilai

Luas_Aja.Cells(3, 1) = SatIn

Luas_Aja.Cells(4, 1) = SatOut

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With Me.SatIn

.AddItem "km²"

.AddItem "hm²"

.AddItem "dam²"

.AddItem "m²"

.AddItem "dm²"

.AddItem "cm²"

.AddItem "mm²"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit further explanations and  code where exactly you get issues;  it's not clear what the (undeclared?) variables like `Nilai` etc. do.

Comment: When printing the units to the sheet, you can replace the 2 with `"²"`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.